# How do I find the last sequential div with a specified class in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, traversal

I have a DOM structure that looks like this:

```
<div id="comment-1234" class="comment">...</div>
<div id="comment-2391" class="comment">...</div>
<div id="comment-1223" class="comment reply">...</div>
<div id="comment-1221" class="comment reply">...</div>
<div id="comment-2333" class="comment">...</div>
<div id="comment-1235" class="comment reply">...</div>
<div id="comment-3333" class="comment reply">...</div>
<div id="comment-5555" class="comment">...</div>
```

In my javascript, I'll have the ID of the div that is getting a new reply, eg `comment-2391`. What I need to do is find that comments last reply, and insert a new div after that. The script is currently using `append('#comment-1234')` and that is working just fine, but it inserts it at the top of the replies.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you should that code in more a hierarchy just to exemplify what's going on here? Also, maybe a before/after shot (this is before, i run my code, and this is what should happen after)

Comment: The replies are children of the 'non-reply' right above them. So, 1223, and 1221 are both replies to the comment 2391. (Please note these numbers are completely arbitrary.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#comment-2391').nextUntil(':not(.reply)').last().after(newcomment);
```

where `newcomment` is the new DIV that you want to insert

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/DaX94/

Comment: This added several new comments, one after each reply. But it's getting closer.

Comment: @Zack - add `.last()` after `nextUntil()` (because it fetches ALL siblings until specified element). And I think it should be `after` method instead of `before`.

Comment: Perfect, @singles. That was a win.

Answer (score 0):

use `insertAfter` or `insertBefore` instead of `append`. see http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

Comment: Sure, I could do that, but `insertAfter` what? I don't know how many replies there are at the time of script execution.